# Bayesian approach on games of chance with physical devices

Tags: bayesian, inference

Suppose we alter side 6 of a die to appear more than 1/6th of the time. We do not know the actual proportion of the time each side of the die will appear because all or some of the other 5 sides do not have the 1/6 proportion too. What do we need to be 99% confidence of each of the 6 sides of this altered die? How does the *a priori* knowledge help us to determine how biased it is? What are the benefits of using Bayes instead of classic study?

Comment: You don't need *any* throws to "have 99% confidence" that all proportions are between 0 and 100%! What is missing from your question is a specification of the *precision* you want to have confidence in; without that, the specific question is unanswerable (although the general question can be addressed).

Comment: You altered the die but the only way to know its actual proportion is by testing. In a fair die it is 0,1666, we only know its prpotion is >0,1666 and that one or all the other side hit < 0,16666. Supose are eager to get 5% or more over the other players, we need >5% edge(0,1666x1,05=0,175). To certify the 0,175%. What are the protocols using Bayes?

Comment: How does Bayes approuch work to get an accurate answer?